# Possible way to create fixtures in the view with Django?

Tags: python, django, view, models, fixtures

as the title says. Is there a possible way to create fixtures in the view with Django?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can dump the database with ./manage.py dumpdata app_name > dump.json
But i want to create a function in the Admin Panel which allows me to download this fixture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `dumpdata` in your view with `call_command` (docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).

See this answer: [How to use call_command with dumpdata command to save json to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075789/how-to-use-call-command-with-dumpdata-command-to-save-json-to-file)