# How to save output from django call_command to a variable or file

Tags: python, django

I am calling commands in Django from within a script similar to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('syncdb')
call_command('runserver')
call_command('inspectdb')
```

How to I assign the output from for instance call_command('inspectdb') to a variable or a file?

I've tried

```
var = call_command('inspectdb')
```

but 'var' remains none: purpose: inspect existing tables in legacy databases not created by django

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make db dumpfile in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546151/how-to-make-db-dumpfile-in-django) and [how to use call command with dumpdata command to save json to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075789/how-to-use-call-command-with-dumpdata-command-to-save-json-to-file)

Answer (score 32):

You have to redirect call_command's output, otherwise it just prints to stdout but returns nothing. You could try saving it to a file, then reading it in like this:

```
with open('/tmp/inspectdb', 'w+') as f:
    call_command('inspectdb', stdout=f)
    var = f.readlines()
```

EDIT:
Looking at this a couple years later, a better solution would be to create a `StringIO` to redirect the output, instead of a real file.
Here's an example from one of [Django's test suites](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca32979cdcafe28cc9cba2c189787e536fef9bb9/tests/user_commands/tests.py):

```
from io import StringIO

def test_command(self):
    out = StringIO()
    management.call_command('dance', stdout=out)
    self.assertIn("I don't feel like dancing Rock'n'Roll.\n", out.getvalue())
```

Comment: tried this, but it does not seem to work, var becomes an empty list while running inspectdb on the commandline yields the inferred models. I'll try subprocess.

Comment: FWIW you were probably not using self.stdout.write() to do the output in the command.

Comment: I don't see how `stdout=f` ever makes it to the Command constructor which is where `stdout` would be used. `call_command` calls  `load_command_class(app_name, name)` and does not pass stdout and the Command is instantiated with no arguments like so `module.Command()`. And here is Command's constructor: `def __init__(self, stdout=None, stderr=None, no_color=False):`

Comment: @Matt: the stdout parameter gets captured in `**options`, transformed into a dictionary called `defaults`, and passed to the command as `command.execute(*args, **defaults)`. So you're right that it's not passed to the constructor; look at `Command.execute` instead.

Comment: link to Django docs on `stdout` arg: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#output-redirection

Answer (score 6):

This is documented in the [**Django Documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#output-redirection) under "Running management commands from your code > Output redirection".

To save to a variable, you could do:

```py
import io
from django.core.management import call_command


with io.StringIO() as out:
   call_command('dumpdata', stdout=out)
   print(out.getvalue())
```

To save to a file, you could do:

```py
from django.core.management import call_command


with open('/path/to/command_output', 'w') as f:
    call_command('dumpdata', stdout=f)
```