# Issue with latin accents on Powershell output redirected to file

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell

I'm using Powershell and *django* web framework for python. This web framework has a utility for dumping data from your database `python manage.py dumpdata`. When you call this command, you will get via *stdout* all your database entries serialized as json (no problems with this output, everything is ok):

```
[
    {
        "model": "user.user",
        "pk": "007a0078-f538-4c01-9a77-694cdd6b142f",
        "fields": {
            "name": "César"
        }
    },
...
]
```

So you easily can use the redirection operator *>* and put the output in a file `python manage.py dumpdata > myfile.json`.
My issue comes after doing that (redirecting the output to a file), if I have letters with latin accents they are replaced for weird characters:

```
{
        "model": "user.user",
        "pk": "fa35df0c-5ce4-4ff0-a4c6-ee25e32930e7",
        "fields": {
            "name": "C¾sar"
        }
},
```

I've also tried to set powershell and python *sys* stdin and out encoding to utf-8 with

-`python manage.py dumpdata | out-file myfile.json -encoding utf8`

-`import sys; sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')`

But still facing the same problem.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question with a more descriptive information. Also I've already tried that solutions, even powershell says its encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: I don't know python at all sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this problem is related to Powershell rather than Python, since its output it's well encoded.

I found a [partial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075789/how-to-use-call-command-with-dumpdata-command-to-save-json-to-file) for this specific case, using the python standard library for creating the desired json file instead the redirection operator *>*